# Nested for loops to convert unstructured data to structured

Tags: python, nested-for-loop

I'm trying to convert unstructured data to structured in Python and need some help in doing that. My dataset has a free text column called "Comments" with 143 rows at this point. I need to create three additional fields from the information present in the Comments column. Below is the sample input data. I need to extract Phone_Call, Successful and Yes as the three words that will then feed into separate columns. All the rest is useless information for me.

-- Type:**Phone_Call**  Contact Attempt:**Successful**  Validation Complete:**Yes**  Notes: Reached out to the customer and contact attempt was successful, completed validation.

-- Type:Email Contact Attempt:Unsuccessful  Validation Complete:No  Notes: Reached out to the customer and contact attempt was successful, completed validation.

This is how I am approaching the issue:

1. I converted the Comments column to String type.
2. I created a for loop to split the Comments for each row (I'm splitting at spaces)
3. I'll create a second nested for loop to then pick the 3rd, 7th and 10th word
4. Finally I'll create a third nested loop to then take the 3rd, 7th and 10th words and transfer them into a three different columns.

I've been able to finish the 1st and the 2nd step but I'm kind of stuck after that. Not sure how to created nested for loops. Any suggestions? The code I've written so far is below:

comments = df['COMMENTS'].astype(str)

for i in range(len(comments)):
(str.split(comments[i]))

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. (including some sample input data)

Answer (score 0):

array Splicing will be your friend.

```
a="Type:Phone_Call Contact Attempt:Successful Validation 
Complete:Yes Notes: Reached out to the customer and contact 
attempt was successful, completed validation"
b= a.split(" ")

c=[None,None,None]
c[0]=b[0][5:]
c[1]=b[2][7:]
```

if the "junk" changes before the ":" char you can use index(":")
to set your splice marks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. However, how do I do this iteratively for all the 143 rows? I'm able to do it for 1 row but it becomes tricky when I try to do it for all the rows. That's where I thought a for loop would help. Are you suggesting that I use splicing within the for loop?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I used your code above to extract the words I 'm interested in. I used a for loop to extract the words I need for all the 143 records using the code below. 
e = []

for i in range(len(comments)):
       e.append(str.split(comments[i]))

c = []

for j in range(len(e)):
        c.append(e[j][2][0:])
         c.append(e[j][6][0:])
         c.append(e[j][9][0:])

Is there a way to directly take these values and input into each required column? With the method above the data gets extracted into a list and I'm having trouble converting that into a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it! Thanks a truck load @IGotThis. Your suggestion got me started. Here's my complete code.

```
comments = df['COMMENTS'].tolist()

# For loop to split the comments list by whitespace and store in list e
e = []

for i in range(len(comments)):
    e.append(str.split(comments[i]))

#Extract all the important information and store in list c       
c = []

for j in range(len(e)):
    c.append(e[j][2][0:])
    c.append(e[j][6][0:])
    c.append(e[j][9][0:])

#Split list c into groups of 3 elements and write to a new dataframe

data = list(zip(*[iter(c)]*3))

f= pd.DataFrame(data[0:], columns=['Contact Type', 'Contact Made', 'Verification Complete'])
```